# Subscriber's onNext action not fired in ViewDidLoad but fired in same class

Tags: c#, .net, events, xamarin.ios, system.reactive

I am working on a chatting mobile application using Xamarin.iOS

I have a class called MessageServices that emits event MessageAddedToDB

And I have a class called Services where I initialize the MessageServices class

Services.cs

```
public MessageServices messageService;

public IObservable<ChatMessage> receivedMessageObservable;
public IObservable<ChatMessage> messageSuccessfullySentObservable;

public Services()
{
    messageService = new MessageServices();
    messageService.MessageAddedToDB += (message) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message.Message); //This gets fired
    }


   AddObservables();
}

public void AddObservables()
{
    receivedMessageObservable = Observable.FromEvent<MessageAddedToDBEventHandler, ChatMessage>(
    (handler) =>
    {
        MessageAddedToDBEventHandler messageAddedToDBEventHandler = (ChatMessage m) =>
        {
            handler(m);
        };
        return messageAddedToDBEventHandler;
    },
    ev => messageService.MessageAddedToDB += ev,
    ev => messageService.MessageAddedToDB -= ev);

    receivedMessageObservable.Subscribe(onNext: (m) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(m.Message); // This gets fired
    }

    messageSuccessfullySentObservable = Observable.FromEvent<MessageSuccessfullySentEventHandler, ChatMessage>
        (
            (handler) =>
            {
                MessageSuccessfullySentEventHandler messageSuccessfullySentEventHandler = (ChatMessage m) =>
                {
                    handler(m);
                };

                return messageSuccessfullySentEventHandler;
            },
            ev => httpHandler.MessageSuccessfullySent += ev,
            ev => httpHandler.MessageSuccessfullySent -= ev
        );
}
```

The subscribe's onNext action and the event handler gets fired

However when subscribing to the receivedMessageObservable from ViewController.cs, the action of the subscriber's onNext action is never called.

In the method ViewDidLoad() of the ViewController I initialize a new instance of Services and I subscribe to its observables

ViewController.cs

```
Services services;

IDisposable receivedMessageSubscriber;
IDisposable messageSentSubscriber;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    services = new Services();
    AddSubscribers();
}

public void AddSubscribers()
{
    receivedMessageSubscriber =
        services
            .receivedMessageObservable
            .Subscribe(onNext: (m) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(m.Message); //This doesn't get fired
            });

    messageSentSubscriber = 
         services
         .messageSuccessfullySentObservable.Subscribe((m) => {
           Debug.WriteLine(m.Message); //This gets fired
    });
}
```

I have other observables such as `messageSuccessfullySentObservable` in the `Services` class where I initialize them the same way as `receivedMessageObservable`. The subscribers in the `ViewController` are also initialized the same way I do with the `receivedMessageSubscriber`. The action of the other subscribers get fired.

Comment: Are you saying that the subscribe method is never called or do you mean that the subscribe delegate is never called?

Comment: @Enigmativity I meant that the subscribe delegate is never called

Comment: There's no such type as `IDisposable<ChatMessage>`. This isn't real code.

Comment: Do you only ever call one `new MessageServices()` (and only one ever `new Services()`)?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I call the services class on multiple view controllers

Comment: Are you then subscribing to one and raising an event in another?

Comment: @Enigmativity the event is being raised when receiving the message
received notification -> do some work using messageService class -> events are emitted

Comment: @Enigmativity you were right, I found out that there are two different instances of the Services class, the class that is firing the messageService events is not subscribing to the observables so I created a static Services class and it worked. Thank you so much for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var messageService = new MessageService();

    var messageReceivedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<MessageAddedToDBEventHandler, ChatMessage>(
        handler =>
        {
            MessageAddedToDBEventHandler messageAddedToDBEventHandler = (ChatMessage m) =>
            {
                handler(m);
                return m;
            };
            return messageAddedToDBEventHandler;
        },
        ev => messageService.MessageAddedToDB += ev,
        ev => messageService.MessageAddedToDB -= ev
    );

    messageReceivedObservable
    .Subscribe((message) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    });         

    messageService.Raise();
    messageService.Raise();
}

public delegate ChatMessage MessageAddedToDBEventHandler(ChatMessage m);

public class MessageService
{
    public event MessageAddedToDBEventHandler MessageAddedToDB;
    public void Raise()
    {
        this.MessageAddedToDB?.Invoke(new ChatMessage());
    }
}

public class ChatMessage { }
```

You must have something going in it your code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I don't know I have tried adding normal eventhandlers, the delegates get called however the action for the subscribe method doesn't get called

Comment: I tried your code on a separate project and you are right it works. @Enigmativity

Comment: @husamdev - Then it's your `messageService` that isn't raising the event.

Comment: It is I added a normal event handler using the +=, and it's getting called. Actually in the same class the subscriber's onNext gets called however on another class it doesn't @Enigmativity

Comment: @husamdev - You need a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I found out that the .subscribe onNext method only gets fired within the same function and same class however on another class it doesn't work I will post another question I tried to produce a minimal example it works @Enigmativity

Comment: @husamdev - On another class? It'll work so long as you share the instance of `messageService`.

Comment: should i create a new question for that? or edit the question? Your answer is right. I created observable from other events the same way and it worked perfectly. But this event in my code in particular is not working. @Enigmativity

Comment: @husamdev - You're trying to get this question in to an answerable state - so you should edit this one. Just make sure that you append the detail and not change the existing question.